# Proving the given Limit Theorem.

Tags: limits

Let $f,g$ be defined on $A\subseteq R$ to $R$ and let $c$ be the cluster point of $A$. Suppose that $f$ is bounded on a neighborhood of $c$ and that : $$\lim_{x\to c}g=0$$

The objective is to prove that: $$\lim_{x \to c}fg=0$$

Now, my question is, isn't the statement '$f$ is bounded on a neighborhood of $c$ where $c$ is a cluster point of $A$...' equivalent to saying $f$ has a limit at $c$ ? And hence $\lim_{x \to c}fg=(\lim_{x \to c}f)(\lim_{x \to c}g)=(\lim_{x \to c}f) \times 0=0$.

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true.

Let $A = \mathbb{R}$. Let $c = 0$. $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 &, x \geq 0 \\ -1 &, x<0 \end{cases}$$

then $f$ doesn't have a limit at $c$.

Hint for the original problem:

Try sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The statement '$f $ is bounded on a neighborhood of $c$, where $c$ is a cluster point of $A$....' is not equivalent to $f$ has a limit at $c$

$f$ is bounded on a neighborhood $U$ of $c$ , hence there ic $M>0$ such that $|f(x) | \le M$ for all $x \in U \setminus \{c\}$.

It follows that

$|g(x)f(x) | \le M|g(x)|$ for all $x \in U \setminus \{c\}$.

Now use that $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=0.$